# How can I suppress the message in Star Team

Tags: excel, compare, starteam

While comparing Excel files, I get the following message:

```
---------------------------
StarTeam
---------------------------
One or more files are not text only!  Do you still want to use alternative compare utility C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe?
---------------------------
Yes   No   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

Comment: What is this? Have you some question?

Comment: The question is in the title.  Beyond Compare is able to compare Excel files and he wants to keep StarTeam from showing an extra, unnecessary prompt every time he compares them.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2007 files are actually compressed archives containing multiple XML "part" files. The error is pretty clear on this. Compressed archives are not text files.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot disable this popup message box.  I have never been able to find any setting or hack to get around it.